# CSS working in Chrome, but not IE or Firefox

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

I'm developing a website for a client and attempting to add multiple menus to a single page.  They are labeled completely differently, and as of now, one of the menus is just a list.  It has no css formatting, and isn't linked to a stylesheet at all. The first menu may be a cause of the problem.  Anyway, I have a list like so:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><span>All</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Test Category</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Another test</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>More tests</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Categories</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

This works just fine in Google Chrome, however whenever I open it in Firefox or Internet Explorer, it formats it like so:
http://gyazo.com/74157a833e0bff1e62a2a6cba5db5f5f

As I'm not quite sure what the source of the problem is, it's too large to post, and CSS and HTML are client side, I'll refrain from posting all of the code here, but feel free to look at my code at http://www.capbig.tk

Note: The server which the website is currently hosted on can become unresponsive occasionally.  It will simply return a blank page.  Please be patient, I know you're trying to help me, so I apologize for any inconvenience.

Any help is *greatly* appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3FXZ3/

Looks the same for me in IE, FF and Chrome

Comment: Some good news, it seems to work fine in Safari and in my firefox. That is if you are talking about the first menu.

Comment: I'm talking about the list below it.  It's going to be a menu, but right now it's only a list.  It's not showing up correctly in IE or FF.  Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: The bottom list without any styles? That still showed up fine in my browsers. Do you try clearing your browser's history to see if that helpes. Sometimes when I'm working with firefox I have to do so if it's a html/css problem.

Comment: spoke too soon... put a clear: both; on your categories id

Comment: Where do I put `clear:both;` in my code? In the styles or in the div tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your style sheet.

```
#categories{
  clear:both;

}
```

Now keep in mind that the list will be pushed down some, but that is because you are positioning your top list up by -100px.

Comment: Sure! When you float an element either right or left to position them you always have to clear it afterward or else that element will inherit the float. I always put a clear:both; because later on some of my styles might change and I'll end up floating the element the other way or doing something else. So it's like a little fail safe. Glad I could help! :) You can read more here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp